# Passport Authentication not working. Passport.serializeUser and passport.deserializeUser never called gets called

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, middleware, passport-local

After I login to my application, passport(local strategy) middleware matches the password to the one stored in database and routes me to the user page but it does not starts the session, due to which I am not able to authenticate post and get request for that user.

After playing around with code I found out that, passport.serializeUser and passport.deserializeUser are never called, I used console.log() to check the same.

I read the passport control flow from this [link](http://toon.io/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow/) and found out that after password is matched and user is passed, the middleware calls req.login which further calls passport.serializeUser, I think in my case the req.login is never called because of which session is not maintained.

I have tried everything but am not able to figure out where I am going wrong.

This is my password Config :-

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/userModel');

module.exports = function(passport){

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
     console.log("serialize");
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
 console.log("deserialize");
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){
  User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user){
      console.log("not user");
      return done(null, false);
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
      if(err) return done(err);
      if(isMatch){
         console.log("pass match");
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        console.log("invalid pass ");
        return done(null, false);
      }
    });
  });
}));
}
```

I always get the response "pass match" if I submit the correct user info in the login page.

This is login page where I have setup Authentication request

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var passportAuth = require('../config/passport');


module.exports = function(app,bodyParser,passport){

     app.use(bodyParser.json());
     app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


      app.post('/api/loginAuth', (req,res,next)=> {
        passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info ) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("inside error");
            return next(err); 
            }
            if (!user) {
                console.log("No user");
                res.status(401).send("not user");
            } else {           
                console.log("verified user");

                res.json(user);
            }
        })(req, res, next); 
     });
    passportAuth(passport);    
}
```

Passport and session setup in my app.js

```
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
// Handle Sessions
app.use(session({
  secret:'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
}));

// Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

This is my angularjs Post request for authentication

```
             $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/api/loginAuth',
                    data: $scope.userinfo,
                    withCredentials: true
                }).success (
                function(response){
                    var message = '<strong>'+response.name+'</strong>        Successfully logged in!! ';
                    sharedDataService.setMessage(message);
                    sharedDataService.setProperty(response.name);
                    $state.go('todo', {username: response.username});

                    });
```

Comment: Are you sure the code where you declare the route for `POST /api/loginAuth` is called _after_ adding the Passport middleware (`passport.initialize()/passport.session()`)?

Comment: Yes I am sure, I have rechecked it :)

Comment: You could check in your browser's dev tools if the session cookie gets set after a succesful login.

Comment: Yes the cookie gets set, but I am not able to authenticate any GET or POST request made by user, and passport.serializeUser and passport.deserializeUser are not called even once.

Comment: Thanks for help. I got my code working. Just needed to add                                         req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) { return res.send(err); }
                 res.json(user);;
                });                In my POST request

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to else part of app.post

```
 req.logIn(user, function(err) {
     if (err) { return res.send(err); }
     res.json(user);
    });
```

Like this

```
app.post('/api/loginAuth', (req,res,next)=> {
        passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info ) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("inside error");
            return next(err); 
            }
            if (!user) {
                console.log("No user");
                res.status(401).send("not user");
            } else {  

                req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                 if (err) { return res.send(err); }
                 res.json(user);
              });

            }
        })(req, res, next); 
     });
```